# No puedo leer un fichero Excel xls

Tags: java, excel

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un fichero llamado agencia.xls con los datos de una agencia pero al intentar leer el archivo me da una excepcion.
Muestro el codigo para leer la excepcion y el fichero excel.

Clase para leer el fichero:

```
package com.dinaprise.lectura.excel;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class LecturaExcel {

    private static final String ARCHIVO_EXCEL = "src\\com\\dinaprise\\lectura\\excel\\agencia.xls";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LecturaExcel test = new LecturaExcel();
        test.leerFichero();

    }

    public void leerFichero() {
        try {
            InputStream excel = new FileInputStream(new File(this.ARCHIVO_EXCEL));
            HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excel);
            HSSFSheet hssfSheet = hssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
            HSSFRow hssfRow;
            HSSFCell cell;
            int rows = hssfSheet.getLastRowNum();
            int cols = 0;
            String cellValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                hssfRow = hssfSheet.getRow(i);
                if (hssfRow == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Row: " + i + " -> ");
                    for (int j = 0; j < (cols = hssfRow.getLastCellNum()); j++) {
                        cellValue = hssfRow.getCell(j) == null ? "" : hssfRow.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.print(cellValue);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

agencia.excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

error:

```
org.apache.poi.hssf.OldExcelFormatException: 

The supplied spreadsheet seems to be Excel 5.0/7.0 (BIFF5) format. POI only supports BIFF8 format (from Excel versions 97/2000/XP/2003)

    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getWorkbookDirEntryName(HSSFWorkbook.java:292)

    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:339)

    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:413)

    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:394)

    at com.dinaprise.lectura.excel.LecturaExcel.leerFichero(LecturaExcel.java:27)

    at com.dinaprise.lectura.excel.LecturaExcel.main(LecturaExcel.java:20)
```

Como puedo evitar esta excepcion porque entiendo que pone version antigua de formato de excel, pero no se que quiere decir con eso.
Al querer guardar el fichero solo me permite estas opciones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo siento por la imagen pero no puedo copiarle guarde con microsoft excel 5.0 pero sigue sin funcionar dando el mismo error

Un saludo

Comment: Pero estas tratando de abrir un excel 2003 o 1997 la pregunta es porque ?

Comment: Deberia de usar excel 5.0 ese puede ser el problema?, no me importa la version mientras tenga la extension xls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu excel es de una versión viejisima (anterior a Office 97) y no esta soportada por POI.

Abre el fichero con un Excel de versión mas nueva (97/2000/XP/2003) y guardalo con esa versión.

Si usas un Excel aun mas nuevo (posterior a 2003) guardalo como xls no como xlsx.

PD: Tambien puedes usar xlsx pero tendras que usar otras clases de POI.

Comment: Vale gracias era porque guardaba con otra version

Answer (score 2):

Sacado de [SO version inglesa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336457/how-to-process-old-excel-xls-files-using-poi):

Para los archivos de formato Excel antiguos, tiene las siguientes alternativas:

1. [HSSF](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/), la implementación `POI` del formato de archivo Excel '97 (-2007).

   - Si solo desea extraer el contenido textual, puede utilizar [OldExcelExtractor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/OldExcelExtractor.html) que solo extraerá el texto y los números del archivo.
   - Si necesita los valores de una celda específica, deberá tomar un `OldExcelExtractor`, procesar el archivo a nivel de registro, y comprobar las coordenadas en [OldStringRecord](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/OldStringRecord.html), [NumberRecord](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/NumberRecord.html), [OldFormulaRecord](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/OldFormulaRecord.html) y derivados.
2. [JXL](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) también puede manejar algunos casos
3. Utilizar un controlador [JDBC / ODBC](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/UseJDBCODBCbridgetoreadfromExcel.htm). No es tan flexible como `HSSF` pero para algunos formatos antiguos es la única forma de extraer la información.